# Which version of openlayers-3 is intended for production use?

Tags: openlayers-3

There seems to be a new Openlayers release coming out about once a month right now (more or less) but I can't find any documentation saying if any 3.x release is intended as "stable" or "long term support".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, anything that's released under https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases (without pre, alpha, beta, gamma, etc. in the version number) should be considered stable.

You can find the entire list of tags here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/tags